# button effects using html and css

Tags: html, css, button

What I want is to apply the link rules to this button, like of a:link, a:hover, etc but I do not want to use a tag as it will change all of my links on the page. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button><a href="#">Button</a></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS

```
   button {
    color: #003739;
    background-color: #00bb89;
    padding: 6px 18px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #007e5c;
    background: linear-gradient(#00dda1, #00956d);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px white;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #d0d0d0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Looking for [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5uGn/)?

Comment: It's almost possible except the `a:visited` feature which is hardly to mimic with pure CSS.

Comment: @KingKing, is it even possible to mimic?

Comment: @W.D. I think it's just possible using script. `a:visited` is a very special feature, even a link you visited several days ago will be styled by `a:visited`, it's hard to mimic. There is some cache memory somewhere storing the visited addresses so we have to do in a similar way ...

Comment: @KingKing the majority of browsers do not disclose this information to prevent websites snooping to see which websites a user has visited.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that's why I said only script can do, do you have any idea for a pure CSS solution replacing the `a:visited` completely?

Comment: @KingKing, you mean using `Javascript`? If I did understand you correctly, I thought you meant mimic `a:visited` without resorting to any of `Javascript` features, but with **CSS only**. I don't think it's possible with `CSS` only.

Comment: @KingKing, OK. saw your new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, it isn't valid for an `a` element to be contained within a `button` element.

What you can do is instead give your `a` element a [button `role` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#aria-role-attribute) and style on that:

```
<a href="#" role="button"></a>
```

```css
a[role="button"]:link {
    ...
}

a[role="button"]:hover {
    ...
}

...
```

Comment: The OP stated clearly that he did not want to use `a` tag. Otherwise we always style the `a` tag to make it look like a button.

Comment: @KingKing OP states that he doesn't want to use an `a` tag as it would change all of the links on his page. This is why in my above example I've added the button `role` to allow to differentiate between those links from the rest.

Comment: Ah I understand what he meant. If so, we can always add `class` instead.

Comment: @KingKing if OP wants the `a` element to render as a button then setting the WAI-ARIA `role` attribute would be more semantically correct than adding a `class`. A class would have to be used, however, if OP wishes to handle IE7 or much older browsers (due to the CSS3 selector).

Comment: What about different kinds of button? for example, round button, circle button, ... does `role` attribute can make it as semantical as `class`? Anyway it's just a problem of individual opinion. It's upto you to use `role`, but if it was me, I would use `class`.

Comment: @KingKing I'm not sure what you mean by a round button or circle button. A button is a button, regardless of how it is styled. Also you're wrong about the specificity, classes and attributes both have the same specificity. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Comment: @James Donnelly I have got the effect I was looking for, one more thing I wanted to ask is: would there be any difference if I were to the id or class instead a role?

Comment: @user3567911 the `id` attribute is unique, so if you do that you'd have to select each ID in your CSS. Otherwise there is no difference between using the `role` attribute and using the `class` attribute CSS-wise.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly and yes one more thing is can I use hover or link effects in css for button only? without putting a tag between the button tag?

Comment: `button:hover`, `button:focus` and `button:active` will all work. The `button` element has no `:link` or `:visited` state.